# How to get variable data out of the html table

Tags: jquery

from the part of table I have,

```
else if (c == 1)
        {
            var startTime = "h:mm AM/PM";
            $("<td>")
                .addClass("tableCell")
                .html("<input type='text' value='" + startTime + "' />")
                .data("col", c)
                .appendTo(trow);

            //col[counter] = startTime;
            //counter++;
            //masterCounter++;
        }
```

out of this, I just want the output of startTime out. However, if I use these codes,

```
var content = document.getElementsByTagName('td');

col[counter] = content[c].innerHTML;
            alert ('td cell number '+(counter)+' contains: ' +col[counter]);
```

I will get input type='text' value='" + startTime + "' / as output for col[counter]

is there anyway so I only get value startTime out of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer! You were correct ShankarSangoli.

I just had to enter

```
col[counter] = $('td').eq(c).find('input').val();
```

instead of

```
content = $('td')
```

Thank you!

Comment: What is the difference between my answer and this answer?

Answer (score 1):

Use this.

```
var content = $('td');

col[counter] = content.eq(c).find('input').val();
alert ('td cell number '+(counter)+' contains: ' + col[counter]);
```

Comment: I need to see your complete code. May be you are doing something wrong.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/SBdWLDqn   there is the 2 function i am working on. createDynamicTable() will create the table I need. cellContent() is the function I have that is suppose to read in the most current data and store into col[counter]. Thank you for all your help!

Comment: I found the answer! You were correct ShankarSangoli.

I just had to enter 

    col[counter] = $('td').eq(c).find('input').val();

instead of 

    content = $('td')

Thank you!